# Latent state model - marginal likelihood

Tags: model-selection, likelihood, hidden-markov-model, latent-variable

Which likelihood do I use to assess model-data-fit for latent space models like e.g. hidden markov models (HMM)?

Let $X$ be the data, $\theta$ the model parameters and $Z$ be the latent variables. My intuition is to look at:

$$p(X|\theta)=\int p(X|Z,\theta)p(Z|\theta)dZ$$

or $\log p(X|\theta)$. For example compute, $p(X|\theta_1)/p(X|\theta_2)$ for some models 1 and 2.

However, I could also evaluate  $p(X|Z,\theta)$ or $p(X,Z|\theta)$, which each answer different questions. Is there any guidance whether these can be useful as well?

Comment: Why don't you generate some data with the estimated parameters and check how close they are to your observed data?

Comment: $Z$ isn't observed, so you marginalize over its distribution to get a more precise expression of the marginal likelihood of $X$.

Comment: @AdamO yes. exactly. I am just curious if, e.g. $X|Z,\theta$ may be good enough to say something meaningfully about model fit, because I would prefer not to do the integral over $Z$.

Comment: No, the |Z means you assume Z is known, it takes a singular value, not only is that a conditional (rather than marginal) expression for the likelihood of $X$, but also you can't even express your uncertainty about Z's actual value.